# How to align in the center-middle but without losing the proportion?

Tags: css

how can I lining up this div in the middle and center but without losing the proportion of the objects and gets deformed on the cellphone?

I tried as follows:

My div:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>Você solicitou o download para o seguinte arquivo:</h1>
            <p class="lead">file.xxx</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>Estamos protegendo a Hacchi Fansub contra bots e pessoas mal intencionadas, para continuar, basta resolver o simples captcha abaixo.</li>
            </ul>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfMECUUAAAAABSGjGQjKQnaRMpUv5rt0MEUnGZ9"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Clique aqui para continuar!" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My modified class:

```
.row {
position: fixed;
left: 35%;
top: 45%;
text-align: center;        
margin-left: -273px; /*half width*/
margin-top: -132px; /*half height*/
width: auto;
}
```

In the computer's browser it was perfect:

[Print 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw3zY.png)

But in the mobile phone navigator:

[Print 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDzut.png)

All the help is welcome, thank you now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `flex` and get the same, even the content comes dynamically.
below i posted just an example to how it works.

i take `height` `100vh` to take full viewport height to get the child in center you can change the value as your need.

```css
.box {
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row wrap;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
 background:tomato;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: I adjusted to 80 and it worked perfectly, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox. On the container apply the following CSS:

```
.container{
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
}
```

This will center the content within this div both vertically and horizontally.

Remove all the other styles you have applied to position the .row div.

Comment: The yellow block was not in the middle of the page... [Print 3.](http://i.imgur.com/1lDOBhF.png)